# Excel T-test 2 sample unequal variance

Tags: t-test, excel

I was recently explaining the  Welsh–Satterthwaite equation's application to two sample t-tests of differing variances, but while going through an example using Excel's built in t-test function (type = 3 for unequal variance) I for the life of me couldn't get my calculation to match up exactly with Excel's built-in t-test function. It's pretty close and I wouldn't want anyone to lose any sleep over this but I've looked around and haven't found any info on the actual code of this function.

You can find the sample workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6lyskWivMC1MWRheVNqY0RaNU0?usp=sharing), hope someone out there has a quick answer to this!

Comment: The difference could be in exactly how the degrees of freedom is calculated as it is fractional.

Comment: I can't find anywhere that Excel actually says it uses Welch-Satterthwaite for the unequal variance case

Comment: Thanks for the help here guys, I guess I just can't think of what other df calculation Excel would be using especially considering I'm so close in using the Welch-Satterthwaite df approach.

Answer (score 1):

P-val (raw) is calculated using a df of 11. That's right, the function rounds DOWN. P-val (round) is the same value as the data analysis toolpak, it also rounds UP to 12 as you did. The function T.TEST uses the decimal value of 11.7, so it gives the most correct value.

I used [this website](https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/tdistribution.aspx) to calculate the p values given any given df value and t stat.